# My mouse cursor Appear and disappear

Tags: technical-issues, pc, mouse

Im using Windows 7, whenever I enter full screen games such as League of Legends, Paladins etc my mouse cursor Appear and disappear.

Has anyone had this issue before and knows what is causing it?

Comment: Unless the mouse cursor remains invisible, this should be normal. Many games use their own mouse cursor, so they hide the regular one.

Comment: no paladins dont have her own mouse cursor and it appear and disappear

Comment: any Solutions ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a gaming issue.  What GPU are you using?

Comment: im using intel.

Comment: Describe "appear and disappear", please. Is it blinking? Is it only visible when you move the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem previously, it was to do with me customising my mouse on windows. To reset your mouse's settings:

1) In control panel, Mouse Properties. Pointer Options Tab:

- Untick Display pointer trails
- Untick Show location.. " " "
- Tick Hide pointer while typing

2) In control panel, Mouse Properties. Buttons Tab:

- Untick Turn on ClickLock

3) If this doesn't fix it, i would suggest changing through the different windows options (windowed, fullscreen, fullscreen windowed).

4) You can also try closing all tabs apart from your game, this often fixed it when i played league of legends (i used dual monitors which was the main issue with league).

5) Try changing the USB port that the mouse is connected to, as it may be a bad connection where the mouse momentarily disconnects.

6) Finally you can try doing windows updates and nvidia updates if you haven't tried that already. Also try updating mouse drivers and monitor drivers. (if not automatic)

[How to update windows](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-check-for-install-windows-updates-2624596)

To update mouse and monitor drivers:

If in windows 10 then 
 - go to device manager
 - go to "mice and other pointing devices" 
 - right click your device and click update drivers
 - go to "Display adapters"
 - right click your device and click update drivers

If in windows 7

- go to device manager
- go to "mice and other pointing devices"
- right click your device and click properties, then select update drivers
- go to "Display adapters"
- right click your device and click properties, then select update drivers

[Other windows versions](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-update-drivers-in-windows-2619214)

Hope this helps (despite being lots of options).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70440/discussion-on-answer-by-branch-my-mouse-cursor-appear-and-disappear).